# Framework for third-party web application extensibility

Tags: widget, intranet, opensocial

I'm interested in people's experiences and opinions about approaches to third-party extensibility in web applications and extending applications into a heterogenous corporate environment. Consider a Salesforce style application.  Users want to be able to extend the Salesforce application itself and share data / functionality outside of Salesforce.

Are these very different tasks?  Should both internal and external extensibility be done using the same approach?  Are there any open frameworks that provide a good starting point?

I've been looking at

- [OpenSocial](http://code.google.com/apis/opensocial/) / [Apache Shindig](http://shindig.apache.org/)
- [NetVibes Universal Widget API](http://dev.netvibes.com/)

but am interested in other options or suggestions.  Both the [Facebook application platform](http://developers.facebook.com/) and the [Yahoo application platform](http://developer.yahoo.com/yap/) roughly fit the bill but aren't open.  Is rolling a new solution a good / bad idea?